# How to manage friends in Firebase chat app - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a Firebase chat app.

I have implemented Firebase email/password authentication. So, when user signups successfully, I have a code through which on every signup/register the app stores user details like name,email, etc in Firebase database under uid node.

Then, the user searches for a friend using a email id, 
if the uid with that email id is present in the firebase database, the function returns true,

then, the app, adds that email id under

```
<FirebaseApp>
     <users>
        ....users details...

     <friends>
        <userid>
            <unique pushed id> : searched email // here the friend's email id is added
```

After adding the new friend,
I am using a recyclerview to show the friend list.
So, the app retrieves all the nodes under friends>> current user's uid>>

As my database structure describes I have only saved friends uid in friends database.

At first step the user will have only friends' email ids. Let say in List `friendsList`.

Then I use this `friendsList` to retrieve all the other details of friends like profile picture, name, contact and etc... which is saved under users node.

But using for each loop retrieving the other details of every friend, and then store in a array list, then paasing that arrayList to adapter and then displaying to recyclerview. is a very time consuming process.

Becuase, it can have other functions too. like converting `Base64` image to bitmap etc.

So every time activity starts , following all above steps, will make a lengthy process.

other that this, I have another way, where I can save friends other's details too under friends node. like name, contact etc. at a point when a new friend added to the database.

But again another question arises.
yes, I can store friend's other details too... But what if the friend updates his profile picture, contact?

So, this procedure is not suitable in my case.

How can I create a whatsapp like friends list in my Firebase app, where I every user's friends list will be always updated with his/her friends details.
also, the will not go under any lengthy process.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to save all the necessary details in the friends node as well.

You can just save the `Opposite_Friends` tag in each user, where just add all the `uids` in whose friends list user is present, So that whenever user updates any detail, you can update it in every users Friends node as well.

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: if it helped you in solving your problem then please upvote, and if it solved your problem then please mark is as an answer so that the question can be closed. Thanks